# Sql readonly access permissions

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I have a SQL Server database where I would like to add a readonly user which it should have only the readonly permission in the database.

I managed to create this user by accessing the server and on the master I run this command:

```
CREATE LOGIN reader WITH password='YourPWD';

CREATE USER readerUser FROM LOGIN reader;

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'readerUser';
```

This work just fine if I want to create a new table I get the error that I don't have enough permission. But the problem is that I don't enough permission to read as well.

In fact if I try to select something I got this error:

> The SELECT permission was denied on the object '', database '', schema ''.

So apparently the code I run it doesn't give read only permission, but it does restrict all the permission for that user.

Can anyone help to understand what I am doing wrong and how can I set the read only permission to this user so I can select and retrieve data but not create tables etc?

EDIT:

```
EXEC sp_addlogin 'account_name', 'password', 'database_name'

USE database_name

CREATE USER 'account_name' FOR LOGIN 'account_name'

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'account_name'

go
```

Comment: What database were you connected to when you ran the above commands? Also, you should really have moved to using `ALTER ROLE` syntax by now, instead of the deprecated `sp_addrolemember` functionality

Comment: Did you run the script in the context of your user database?

Comment: I logged in as admin, on the `master` database I run the command. logged out from the server and logged in as the new user. `ALTER ROLE` can set the user permissions?

Comment: Then the `USER` was created in the `master` database, @NaydenVan . It has no permissions in any other database as it doesn't have a `USER` mapped to them. You need to change the context of database you are connected to (using `USE`) to `CREATE` the `USER` in  the right database(s).

Comment: @Larnu 
```
EXEC sp_addlogin 'account_name', 'password', 'database_name'

USE database_name

CREATE USER 'account_name' FOR LOGIN 'account_name'

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'account_name'

go
```
something similar can work? should still run on the master first right? I cannot find any solution with alter role

Comment: [Edit] your qusetion, @NaydenVan ...

Comment: As for `ALTER ROLE`, see [ALTER ROLE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-role-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15); which is also linked to on the deprecated `sp_addrolemember`'s documentation: [sp_addrolemember (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addrolemember-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created the `USER` in `master`, not the database you need it in. Your script should look something like this:

```sql
USE master;
GO
CREATE LOGIN reader WITH password='SecurePassword';
GO
USE YourDatabase; --Obviously replace:
GO
CREATE USER reader FOR LOGIN reader;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER reader;
GO
```

---

Turns out, from the comments, the OP is using Azure SQL Database *not* a SQL Server instance, thus creating the `LOGIN` is irrelevant . Instead you need to initially connect to the right database, ***not*** `master`, and then create your `USER`:

```sql
CREATE USER reader WITH PASSWORD = N'SecurePassword';
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER reader;
```

Comment: Hi Larnu, I tried you code but I get the following error `USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect to a different database.` could this problem be related to azure sql as I am running it in azure cloud?

Comment: ... You're using Azure SQL Database *not* SQL Server... That's important information -_-

Comment: sorry mate. I updated my tag. thank you for your help and sorry if I wasted your time :(